# Use chromecast inside chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cast

I am trying to developp an extension to add chromecast capabilities to a website that doesn't support it. The idea is to inject in the page the require javascript code to modify a default html 5 player with a one that support chromecast.
I am trying using CastVideos-chrome and CastHelloVideo-chrome from github.

I first download the [cast_sender.js](https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js) and inject it with content_scripts directive in the manifest.json of my extension.
I can see in the javascript console the message "Found cast extension: boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd ". I then add a second a second javascript file using again content_scripts directive which is largly inspire by example codes from github.
The code is block in :

```
if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
  setTimeout(this.initializeCastPlayer.bind(this), 1000);
  return;
}
```

I add debug to see value of chrome.cast and chrome.cast.isAvailable.
chrome.cast contains lot of information generated by cast_send.js and

```
<script>src=​"chrome-extension:​/​/​boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/​cast_sender.js">​</script>
```

​is injected in the website code but chrome.cast.isAvailable is never defined.

Is there some limitation to use chromecast inside a extension and is there to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be dealing with 2 different JS worlds here, the world of the page (main world) and the world of the extension (content script).

See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was the syntax. Change the following:

```
<script>src=​"chrome-extension:​/​/​boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/​cast_sender.js">​</script>
```

To:

```
<script src="chrome-extension:​/​/​boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/​cast_sender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Probably just a typo in the question.